# free javascript obfuscator?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

thanks for your attention and  precious time.

Please mention some free javascrpt obfuscator software that can compress, obfuscates and encode javascript for protection. I serached but could found web based only and those which are free and desktop are not good. Please guide and help me.

thanks

Comment: @polemon you might want to protect the source code of your webapp for instance. Too bad it's impossible though.

Comment: Why would anyone need that? What a strange and objectionable, negative statement. The reasons are obvious : to provide a modicum of protection for your code (nothing is really secure of course) and also to minimise the code footprint for faster loading times. Did it not cross your mind that there is  reason obfuscators/compressors  exist?

Comment: I love the fact that some very helpful answers can be found here even though the question was closed as "off topic". I hate this statement with a passion: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." Any kind of question may attract opinionated answers and spam! That doesn't mean those answers don't have value from the point of view of the vast majority of people who come here! This is oppressive control of the many by the few.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Minification "compresses" code.

Packing "compresses" and "obfuscates" code.

The most popular packer I believe to be:
http://dean.edwards.name/packer/

However Google Closure one of the highest rated minifiers can also do packing with additional options:
http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html#enable

Comment: thanks balupton,

Packer is good but it is web based, is there any tool desktop based ?

thanks

Comment: Google Closure is a java file you can download and run via the command line. It's my preferred method for minification (as well as jQuery's) and as stated it can do additional things like packing by passing some additional command line arguments.

Answer (score 12):

#### Obfuscation: Don't do it.

No matter how hard you try to obfuscate JS, it's easy to de-obfuscate it. There are many plugins available for this purpose. For example, there is [Javascript Deobfuscator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10345/) for Firefox.

#### Do minify though.

It will save you and your users some bandwidth, improve load times and everybody's happy.

[Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_ui.html)
[MinifyJS](http://www.minifyjs.com/javascript-compressor/)
[YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)
[many more...](http://www.google.com/search?q=js+minifier)

Comment: Wait a minute; obfuscation does not offer fool proof "protection", but it does make reading the code more time consuming.

Comment: @cmc My point is that it's pointless because it offers nearly no protection.

Comment: Obfuscation can really work good, the Firefox Javascript Deobfuscator doesn't really deobfuscate it (I obfuscated my code with 2 different obfuscators)

Comment: @steebchen It's still a futile exercise that can only delay the inevitable.

Answer (score 3):

[YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) is generally considered the best option for minifying JavaScript. But don't imagine anything will protect your code if anyone wants to steal it — that's a fool's errand and no professional will waste his time that way.

Comment: The HTML5 platform is very compelling, but this intellectual property security problem is really bad. Technically you can't run any kind of code on a client and expect it to be secure, but lots of client side applications are sold and do just fine even though all the IP is sitting there running right on the client. Distributed binaries seem to be sufficiently obscure to prevent pirating from being cost effective, in most cases. But JavaScript obfuscation can be undone well enough and easily enough that it has fairly limited utility. I wonder if WebAssembly can help us with this.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest another tool to minify / compress /obfuscate javascript: http://jscrambler.com

Currently it is web only but an API is coming that will allow for remote call.

I have found a list of known javascript obfucators here: http://www.malwareguru.org/mediawiki/index.php/Collection_of_tools_for_javascript_obfuscation_%28javascript_packers%29

Answer (score 2):

Obfuscriptor is another free Javascript obfuscator.

**EDIT: Dead link, this is now a NSFW website**  (http://www.obfuscriptor.com/)

**Last Archive.org save:** https://web.archive.org/web/20140202025012/http://www.obfuscriptor.com/

The obfuscated code really looks like garbage. Something like f/$873h3#"!=]f.

And for non trivially small files it provides the best compression rates I've seen.

Comment: Agree! I use obfuscriptor.com to obfuscate my JS, looks like encrypted, not like the simple remove-spaces-and-rename-variables obfuscation that YUI or Google provide...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy web based one:

http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx

Also, remember that if an attacker is determined enough, they will be able to put together the original code, obfuscating just deters casual attackers and just makes it harder for the more experienced ones.

Answer (score 1):

Obfuscators can be beautified quite easily. [This](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator) TypeScript project is not a silver bullet by any means, but does make beautifying MUCH more difficult depending on the parameters used.

Strings are converted into hexadecimal and you will never be able to get your original code back so keep a safe copy.

Also, you can run a minifier before using this but do not run this and then use a minifier. Things will likely break.

[Here](https://javascriptobfuscator.herokuapp.com/) is an online playground to get your feet wet.

If you don't want to use webpack, gulp, grunt - the online playground is also [available](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator-ui) for you to run locally credit to Tiago Serafim.

JavaScript Obfuscator Tool - Credit - Timofey Kachalov

Answer (score 0):

Hey there is no such thing.

Javascript needs to be interpreted by the browser, and hence has to be readable by the browser... and thus cannot be obfuscated. The ones you find on google are as good as it gets. They can make the javascript slightly hard to read by hand, but on the other hand it's pretty easy to de-obfuscate them.

There is one option if you want to do something to protect your code. You can move your code to the serverside using a server side javascript solution, such as node.js. This will probably make your app overall more complicated but might be worth it if you are really serious about protecting your code.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of `obfuscating` is:
changing the code in a matter that the code will be less readable, but EXACT same functionality and logic!

A very good [free obfuscator](http://freejsobfuscator.com/)  that I'm using usually, because it is:
1] free :)
2] **one way obfuscating!**  some tools change your functions, by 'eval', which can easily show your ORGINAL code.
3] add random code inside for harder tracking.
4] and also, cleans line-breaks + empty spaces.

Full URL: http://freejsobfuscator.com/

Answer (score 0):

I found an awesome obfuscator tool at here: http://javascript-obfuscator.org.
The tool give me bunch of options which I can choose to protect my js source code. However, some of them would make a trade-off between code protection and code size / speed.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.